# How to boost individual words in a elasticsearch match query

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I want to query "Best holiday places to visit during summer" in a Elasticsearch cluster. But I want holiday, visit and summer to have high priority than other words:

Something Like this: Best holiday^4 places to visit^3 during summer^2.

I know about field boosting but what I want to do is not achievable by boost. 
Basically I want to boost individual words.

Does any one have any idea about doing this in Elasticsearch 5.6 above??

Answer (score 1):

You could use `query_string` to boost individual terms like this:

```
{ 
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["content", "name"],
            "query" : "Best holiday^4 places to visit^3 during summer^2"
        }    
    }
}
```